# How to use ScrollView with multiple <include> layouts in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

first question here, so apologies in advance if I forget to add anything or mess up formatting. I have a fragment that I would like to put a ScrollView on, and inside of that ScrollView I want to be able to scroll between two different XML layouts I've created. I am using <include> to add these layouts to a LinearLayout, and then putting that LinearLayout inside of the ScrollView. However, this doesn't seem to work at all, and all I see is the first <include> layout and I am not able to scroll vertically to view the second layout. However, when I test out the ScrollView with a LinearLayout containing simple ImageViews and TextViews, it seems to work just fine. I'm just confused on the proper way to use ScrollView with multiple XML layouts.

Here is a layout that I am including:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#80000000"
android:alpha=".8"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="190dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/originium_shard"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOriginium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/average_sans"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:shadowDx="8"
        android:shadowDy="8"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="A deadly disease."
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/redrectWorld1"
        android:layout_width="273dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/breakingNewsWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/breakingNewsWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/breakingNewsWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/breakingNewsWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/redrect"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breakingNewsWorld1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/press_start_2p"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:text="BREAKING NEWS"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.519"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blackrectWorld1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:alpha=".7"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/redrectWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/redrectWorld1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blackrect"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/introblurb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="@string/intro_blurb"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/blackrectWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/blackrectWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/blackrectWorld1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/blackrectWorld1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The other layout that I want to scroll to is almost the same, so I will omit the code. Here is my fragment's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/originium_bg"
tools:context=".Landing2Fragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/world_1">
    </include>

    <include
        layout="@layout/world_2">
    </include>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[Here is an image of what the emulator looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3PLX.png)
It is stuck on this first layout and I cannot scroll at all. Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

EDIT: So I was still unable to find the solution to my original problem, but I was able to awkwardly work around it. I think it has something to do with ConstraintLayout being within a LinearLayout, because when I recreated my layout pages using RelativeLayout instead of ConstraintLayout that I originally had, using <include> works and I can scroll properly. Still not sure what the exact issue is, but I believe it has something to do with that ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Nice ... The whole idea is that scroll view takes only one direct child ... If you need the layout to be in it, add linear layout to the scroll view. Now you can include the two layout in the linear layout...